# Jquery Custom Tab persistence with Cookies

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-tabs, jquery-cookie

I have a simple tab setup using jquery (and ASP.NET MVC3 Razor engine).
Here is the html:

```
<ul id="tabul">
    <li id="litab" class="ntabs add"><a href="" id="addtab">+</a></li>
    <li id="hometab" class="ntabs">Home</li>
    <li id="componentstab" class="ntabs">Components</li>
    <li id="documentstab" class="ntabs">Documents</li>
    <li id="userstab" class="ntabs">Users</li>
</ul>
<div id="tabcontent">
    <div id="hometabcontent" class="tabcontainer">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("GetTest1Tab");
        }
    </div>
    <div id="componentstabcontent" class="tabcontainer" style="display: none;">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("GetTest2Tab");
        }
    </div>
    <div id="documentstabcontent" style="display: none;" class="tabcontainer">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("GetTest3Tab");
        }    
    </div>
    <div id="userstabcontent" style="display: none;" class="tabcontainer">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("GetTest4Tab");
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the JQuery:

```
        $(function () {
            var total_tabs = 0;

            $("#tabcontent .tabcontainer").hide();
            $("#hometabcontent").fadeIn('slow');

            $("#addtab, #litab").click(function () {
                total_tabs++;
                $("#tabcontent .tabcontainer").hide();
                addtab(total_tabs);
                return false;
            });
            $("#hometab").click(function () {
                $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
                $("#hometab").addClass("ctab");
                $("#tabcontent .tabcontainer").hide();
                $("#hometabcontent").show();
                $("#hometabcontent").children().show();
            });

            $("#componentstab").click(function () {
                $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
                $("#componentstab").addClass("ctab");
                $("#tabcontent .tabcontainer").hide();
                $("#componentstabcontent").fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $("#documentstab").click(function () {
                $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
                $("#documentstab").addClass("ctab");
                $("#tabcontent .tabcontainer").hide();
                $("#documentstabcontent").fadeIn('slow');
            });
            $("#userstab").click(function () {
                $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
                $("#userstab").addClass("ctab");
                $("#tabcontent .tabcontainer").hide();
                $("#userstabcontent").fadeIn('slow');
            });

            function addtab(count) {
                var closetab = '<a href="" id="close' + count + '" class="close">&times;</a>';
                $("#tabul").append('<li id="t' + count + '" class="ntabs">Tab ' + count + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + closetab + '</li>');
                $("#tabcontent").append('<div id="c' + count + '" class="tabcontainer">Tab Content ' + count + '</div>');

                $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
                $("#t" + count).addClass("ctab");

                $("#t" + count).bind("click", function () {
                    $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
                    $("#t" + count).addClass("ctab");
                    $("#tabcontent .tabcontainer").hide();
                    $("#c" + count).fadeIn('slow');
                });

                $("#close" + count).bind("click", function () {
                    // activate the previous tab
                    $("#tabul li").removeClass("ctab");
                    $("#tabcontent .tabcontainer").hide();
                    $(this).parent().prev().addClass("ctab");
                    $("#c" + count).prev().fadeIn('slow');

                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    $("#c" + count).remove();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
```

It's pretty simple.  Just hides any tab content that isn't active.  When a new tab is added, a new `<li>` is added in "tabul" and a new `<div>` is added in "tabContent".  The first four tabs are static and will not ever be closed (which is why they are statically added in the beginning).

My question is on persistence of the tabs when the page is refreshed, I want to maintain a session.  What would the correct way of going about this be?  Could I use the JQ Cookie plugin?  If so how?